# Network Censorships -- What are some strong http tunnelers?

Tags: windows, proxy

Okay some websites have been blocked by my ISP. I need a way to circumvent this, they've stopped everything I've thrown at them.

Tor - Blocked

Freedom - Blocked

Privoxy - Blocked

Can you recommend some? I'm using windows 7

Comment: Anybody.................?

Comment: Cancel your contract. Seriously. ISPs are about making money. They won't make money if they are boycotted for such practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JAP](http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html), [Cyberghost](http://cyberghostvpn.com/), [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de/)

maybe your provider just imposes dns blocks, in that case see http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/network/dns.html for a list of uncensored dns servers go here : http://wiki.ak-zensur.de/index.php/Unzensierte_DNS_Server